# how to return specific ammount of list entries - c# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, pagination

for example i have some list with 120 entries.

```
 Threads = new List<Thread>();
```

and i will return to show in my view just 10 of them.

I have a properties like, TotalCount, TotalPages, PageSize=10, PageIndex.
How can I do that?

Take care,
Ragims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();

// Fill the list

threads.Skip(PageSize * (PageIndex - 1)).Take(PageSize);
```

Or, if PageIndex is zero based (the first page is PageIndex = 0) then:

```
threads.Skip(PageSize * PageIndex).Take(PageSize);
```

Comment: i cant use a linq... because all my logic is altready build with c# and sql statements

Comment: @Ragims - I'm confused. You're still filling a List and you want to page through the List. Once the List is filled, your logic and SQL has already been run, has it not?

Answer (score 3):

How about `Threads.Skip(PageIndex*PageSize).Take(PageSize)` ?

(Edit: this depends on linq extension methods)

Comment: do you have some idea to do that with poor sql statements and c#?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this give you the page after the one you're looking for? Page 1 will skip 1 * 10 and give you the next 10 which is results 11 - 20.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, but i not using linq in my project. i am trying to do it without linq.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search on "Paging with LINQ" and you'll get a ton of ideas.  LINQ really makes it easier to do this sort of thing.

Comment: all my logic is already with sql statements in code. its hard to use linq now

Comment: What do you mean it's hard to use LINQ?

Comment: can i use a linq if i have already implemented logic with c# and sql statements as SqlCommand.Text?? I never worked with linq. I dont know if i canuse it additionaly to my already implemented logic

Comment: @Ragmis: Your question doesn't say anything about SQL statements.  Including that in your original question would have gotten you better answers.

Comment: Bertrand Marron: I said LINQ makes it easier.